# Squirrels and cedar damage

Tags: pest-damage, cedar

I have a cedar that's been thick and beautiful for 25 years. This year, and for the first time ever, the neighborhood squirrel decided it wanted cedar branches for it's nest. Within one day, the squirrel had chewed off half the cedar's green ends leaving just the stems. Can green grow back from these stems?